# Fetch two rows of different values of the same column from database (MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql

I've this bizarre requirement where two input filter will pick different rows that has column value type in that two input box.

Sample code:

```
Row value1    value2
1.    2         1
2.    1         3
3.    2         1
4.    1         1
5.    1         1
6.    2         1
```

HTML:

```
<input type="number" name="home1"> <input type="number" name="away1">
<input type="number" name="home2"> <input type="number" name="away2">
```

PHP:

```
    //total scores 1
    if(isset($_POST['home1']))
    {
        $home1 = $_POST['home1'];
    }
    if(isset($_POST['away1']))
    {
        $away1 = $_POST['away1'];
    }

    //Score 2
    if(isset($_POST['home2']))
    {
        $home2 = $_POST['home2'];
    }
    if(isset($_POST['away2']))
    {
        $away2 = $_POST['away2'];
    }
```

Fetch values from database

```
if(!empty($home1) && !empty($away1) && !empty($home2) && !empty($away2))
 {
   echo "Valid inputs";
   $result = $wpdb->get_results ( "SELECT * FROM  `tbl_api` WHERE 
   (`value1` = $home1 AND `value2` = $away1) AND 
   (`value1` = $home2 AND `value2` = $away2)");
 }
```

What I actually want here is to query two input fields at a time and display result as per the input value. For eg: if I put 1&2 in first input field, it will display table rows where the column value of value1 & value2 is 1&2..

At the same time if I input 1&1 in next input box, it will display all the rows containing 1&1 column values.

To sum up: It should be displaying rows where the column values are 1&2 and 1&1 (as per the input values in both column).

When i do this - it only shows the result of first or second input values not both of them at a time (which actually is my requirement).

If someone can shed light on this - would appreciate voluntary help.

Comment: `value1` can not be equal to `1` and `2` at the same time!
So, you need to use JOIN or UNION.

Comment: @HamzaAbdaoui Is not JOIN or UNION suppose to be use for different tables? In my case, they belong to the same table & column - it's just the values of two distinct filters to fetch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider this table :

```
Row_ID   value1    value2
1        2         1
2        1         3
3        2         1
4        1         1
5        1         1
6        2         1
```

Now, if the user input is :

```
home1 = 2 and away1 = 1
home2 = 1 and away2 = 1
```

This query would do the job :

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl_api 
WHERE (value1 = 2 AND value2 =1 )
      OR 
      (value1 =1  AND value2 = 1);
```

The output is :

```
Row_ID   value1    value2
1        2         1
3        2         1
4        1         1
5        1         1
6        2         1
```

Comment: Really appreciate for taking time to response. While it got working with none '0' numbers but that is not in the case where user input '0' & '0' as PHP treat '0' as null.  My values has '0' too that's creating problem..

Answer (score 0):

Well, at first, never trust userinput, use PDO to handle params from user.
You have logic mistake in query because value2 can't be valued as 1 and 2 in same time.

```
WHERE 
(`value1` = $home1 AND **`value2` = $away1**) AND 
(`value1` = $home2 AND **`value2` = $away2)**");
```